# Cout doesn't work after return

Tags: c++

Cout (and everything else I've attempted to put after the return) doesn't work when placed after the return in this function. What's wrong?

```
   float tanDegrees() {
    string i;
    double iDouble;
    string choice;

    cout << "Give me a number to find the value of degrees in. ";
    getline(cin, i);

    iDouble = stod(i);

    double PI = 3.14159265359;

    float answer = tan((PI / 180)*iDouble);

    cout << "Test!" << endl;

    return answer;

    cout << "Test!" << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return causes you to leave the function's scope. So anything after "return" won't be touched.

Comment: I want to use the "answer" value to create another value, both of which I'd like to have used after the function is done running. Should I place the returns for both of them at the very end of the function?

Comment: @Rocky then you should use the value after the return of tanDegrees() not in the function itself.